# How to set relative path to a "a href"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, relative-path

For example, I provide an relative to an social sharing plugin

```
../../test.html
```

as a link

It show as

```
http://../../test.html
```

Is there any way to convert the path to absolute if it requires an "http://" before the path ? Thanks

Edit:

The place I put the path

```
$('#sina').attr('href', "javascript:void((function(s,d,e,r,l,p,t,z,c){var%20f='http://v.t.sina.com.cn/share/share.php?appkey=',u=z||d.location,p=['&url=',e(u),'&title=',e(t||d.title),'&source=',e(r),'&sourceUrl=',e(l),'&content=',c||'gb2312','&pic=',e(p||'')].join('');function%20a(){if(!window.open([f,p].join(''),'mb',['toolbar=0,status=0,resizable=1,width=440,height=430,left=',(s.width-440)/2,',top=',(s.height-430)/2].join('')))u.href=[f,p].join('');};if(/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent))setTimeout(a,0);else%20a();})(screen,document,encodeURIComponent,'','','" + imgStr + "','" + shareDes + "','','utf-8'));");
```

I dont know how the path works but it works if I provide with absolute path

`#sina` is a `<a href></a>` element while imgStr is the link provide

I check the source code after running the website , if it is relative path , it show as `"http://../../test.html"`

Comment: I'm afraid your question is very unclear. You provide the relative path *where*? What does that markup/code look like? *"It show as..."* Where? What are you looking at?

Comment: What is the server side platform?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for unclear , let me edit it

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the plugin, it's adding the `http://` prefix, so your relative path becomes absolute.

Comment: @Barmar you are correct , Is the workaround replace ../ to location.href or something similiar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
location.hostname+location.pathname+your_relative_path
```

This will give you a combination of the path to your current page (minus the actual file name if there was one in the url) with your relative address in `your_relative_path`.

So, something like `http://www.mypage.com/contents/level1/en-us/page2/../../test.html` would be the result in the end.

Comment: also check for (and in absence add) / before your relative? :D +1 if you could confirm browser compatibility ^^

Comment: it seems I should use location.pathname to replace the ../../

Comment: `location.pathname` will give the pathname of the current page (the page from where you execute your JavaScript). The path for `test.html` is two levels up from there. @JaakKütt: Valid point with the slashes, but since in this example the OP wants to move up two levels we can be certain that there *is* a slash at the end of `location.pathname` - at least in this case ;-)